# Prevent reloading page after submiting a form asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

so i got this div. In this div I have a textarea and its editable so i put it in a form to submit the changes and it works this far but i got something that bothers me a little:
after submitting and saving the changes to the database it refreshes the page but i only want to save the changes and do nothing else. Now my Question is how do I prevent it from refreshing or redirecting and just save the changes?

This is my Controller:

```
namespace ChangeLogManager___Mit_Vorlage.Controllers
{
    public class BeschreibungController : Controller
    {


        public JsonResult getText(int xVersionID)
        {
            ProgrammInfo lInfo = new ProgrammInfo();
            var lBeschreibung = lInfo.getBeschreibung(xVersionID);
            return Json(lBeschreibung, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult SaveText(BeschreibungModel xData)
        {
             using (var ctx = new ChangeLog_DEVEntities())
             {
                 var lVersion = (from p in ctx.Version where p.ID == xData.ccVersionID select p).FirstOrDefault();
            // var lVersion = ctx.Version.Where(p => p.ID == xData.ccVersionID).FirstOrDefault();
            lVersion.Changelog = xData.ccBeschreibung;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }


        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

}
```

I do know that the `RedirectToAction`does the refresh. Is there possibly a replacement for it that does... like nothing, just saving the changes made ?

and this is my div (its a partial view in the index page where the form is located aswell):

```
@model Domain.src.Daten.BeschreibungModel



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Site.css" />

@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.ccBeschreibung)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ccVersionID)
```

I hope someone can help me.
(sorry if there are any mistakes in my english)
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: there is something known as ajax call to achieve this

Comment: instead of Html.BeginFrom ise Ajax.BeginForm helper for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like this in your button click event:

```
$("#UpdateUserForm").submit(function (e)
    {
        var isValid = $("#UpdateUserForm").valid();
        if (!isValid)
            return;

        //This is important as it prevents the form being submitted twice
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $("#UpdateUserForm").attr("action"),
            data: $("#UpdateUserForm").serialize(),
            success: function (response)
            {                    
                var status = '';
                status = response.Status;
                ShowAlert(response.Status, response.Message, status.toLowerCase());
            }
        }).error(function () {
            ShowAlert("An Error Occurred", "An error occurred while attempting to process your request. If the problem persists, please contact your administrator.", "error");
        });
    });
```

Comment: What do I do with my Html.BeginForm do i need to change it to the ajax.BeginForm helper mentioned above and if so how?

Comment: I've always done it manually, i.e using the regular Html.BeginForm helper. This creates a form which can be submitted automatically when the submit button is clicked. You can also do it programmatically using jQuery. I have updated the example code as it's a bit more descriptive. In this case, the Ajax call is made when the submit button is clicked. You can also do this programmatically using something like $("#UpdateUserForm").submit(); the e.preventDefault(); is important as it prevents double submitting

Comment: Okay that helps me alot, thank you. Im trying my best to implement it now.

Comment: Glad to help. Can you mark the answer as correct if you think it is please?

Comment: I dont know if its the answer like I said im going to try it with this and if it works for me then I will mark it. But give me some time because Im still new to all this.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine :D Thanks again

Comment: Glad to hear it! You can do some pretty awesome things with jQuery and Ajax - best of luck with it!